# Django ajax: in call does not make any changes

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-views

So I made this ajax view for my user model

```
def new_notification(request):
    user = request.user
    user.profile.notifications += 1
    user.save()

    return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', [user]), safe=False)
```

I extends my user model with an Integerfield of notification, but when I call the ajax it does not give +1 to my notification model, does anybody know what is going on?

my urls.py

```
url(r'^ajax/new_notification/$', new_notification),
```

and my ajax call

```
$.get('/ajax/new_notification/')
```

my user profile model

```
class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    """
    Profile model
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        verbose_name=_('User'),
        #to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        to = User,
        related_name='profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image')
    notifications = models.FloatField(default='0')
```

Comment: If you're doing this via ajax, `request.user` is anonymous. You can gather the user in the template, then send that to your function: `def new_notification(request, user_id):`

Comment: @GAEfan how can I do this. I´m new to django

Comment: Show your ajax call code.

Comment: @GAEfan Now my views and ajax call are in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, change url:

```
url(r'^ajax/new_notification/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9/_\.-]*)', new_notification),
```

Then, change the view function:

```
def new_notification(request, username):
    #user = request.user
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    
    print(user.profile)
    print(user.profile.notifications)
    user.profile.notifications += 1
    print(user.profile.notifications)
    user.profile.save()
    
    #user.save()

    return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', [user]), safe=False)
```

Then, in your ajax call in the template, change the url to: `/ajax/new_notification/{{ user.username }}`

Comment: is not changing the value of notifications

Comment: I try it but not changing the notifications val

Comment: this happened (AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'get_profile')

Comment: Show your User and UserProfile? models.

Comment: OK, try the new code.  `print()` functions to track.